# App crashes after button clicked with empty edittext

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext

I am working on BMI calculator app. It has got two editText, one button and three textView. If you click the button, you get your BMI, but when one or both edittext fields are empty, the app crashes. I can't see any mistake in my code. Can you help me someone?
Thanks a lot

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
}

public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

        EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
        EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
        TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

        float weight;
        if ("".equals(weightText.getText())) {
            weight = 1;
        } else {
            weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
        }

        float height;
        if ("".equals(heightText.getText())) {
            height = 1;
        } else {
            height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
        }

        float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
        String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
        resultText.setText(bmiValue + "-" + bmiInterpretation);
    }
}

private float calculateBMI (float weight, float height) {
    return (float) (weight / ((height / 100) * (height / 100)));
}

private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {
    if (bmiValue < 16) {
        return "Severely underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue < 18.5) {
        return "Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue >= 18.5 && bmiValue < 25) {
        return "Normal";
    } else if (bmiValue >= 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
        return "Overweight";
    } else if (bmiValue >= 30) {
        return "Obese";
    } else {
        return "Incorrect BMI";
    }
}
```

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions.

Comment: Your `if` statements should use the `toString()` method...`if ("".equals(weightText.getText().toString()))` but a `try/catch` would be better (easier?). And yes, what Xaver said.

Comment: I can't see the button in your code...

Comment: @AlexBalo probably set in xml `public void calculateClickHandler(View view)`

Comment: A few improvements: This is wrong `"".equals(heightText.getText())` instead do this `heightText.getText().toString().isEmpty()`. This cast to `float` is redunant: `return (float) (weight / ((height / 100) * (height / 100)));`, you don't need that here you are only working with `float`. And you should save the instances of your `EditTexts` globally.

Comment: Appending the stack trace of the error would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your app crashes are these `if` statements:

```
if ("".equals(weightText.getText())) {
    weight = 1;
}
```

`weightText.getText()` does not return a `String`, but a `Editable`. Additionally `Strings` have a method called `isEmpty()` to check if they are empty. So replace your ifs with something like this:

```
if(weightText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `heightText.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your EditText with "". 
for example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/weightText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
 />
```

and change

```
weightText.getText()
```

to

```
weightText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in your post you might try:

```
float weight;
if (weightText.getText() == null || "".equals(weightText.getText().toString())) {
    weight = 1;
} else {
    weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
}

float height;
if (heightText.getText() == null || "".equals(heightText.getText().toString())) {
    height = 1;
} else {
    height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
}
```

Hope this helps.